# Convert Standard Numeric Format with culture to Custom Numeric Format

Tags: c#, formatting

In C#, is there a way to get the equivalent custom numeric format for a standard numeric format with a specified user's culture?

Examples (not sure my conversion are right) :

- C3 in fr-FR = 0.000 '€'
- D2 = 0.00
- P0 = %#0

See those links :

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `CultureInfo` you can examine the `NumberFormat` property of type [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get all the information that .NET uses when formatting different number types. E.g.:

```
var frenchCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
Console.WriteLine(frenchCultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol);
```

This will print `€`. To reconstruct the complete format you will have to inspect multiple properties on the `NumberFormat` property. This can become quite tedious. As an experiment I have tried to write the code necessary to format a `Decimal` using the `C` format specifier:

```
var value = -123456.789M;
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("as-IN");
var numberFormat = cultureInfo.NumberFormat;

// Create group format like "#,##,###".
var groups = numberFormat
  .CurrencyGroupSizes
  .Reverse()
  .Select(groupSize => new String('#', groupSize));
var format1 = "#," + String.Join(",", groups);

// Create number format like "#,##,##0.00".
var format2 = format1.Substring(0, format1.Length - 1)
  + "0." + new String('0', numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits);

// Format the number without a sign.
// Note that it is necessary to use the correct CultureInfo here.
var formattedNumber = Math.Abs(value).ToString(format2, cultureInfo);

// Combine sign, currency symbol and number.
var currencyPositivePatterns = new Dictionary<Int32, String> {
  { 0, "{0}{1}" },
  { 1, "{1}{0}" },
  { 2, "{0} {1}" },
  { 3, "{1} {0}" }
};
var currencyNegativePatterns = new Dictionary<Int32, String> {
  { 0, "({0}{1})" },
  { 1, "-{0}{1}" },
  { 2, "{0}-{1}" },
  { 3, "{0}{1}-" },
  { 4, "({1}{0})" },
  { 5, "-{1}{0}" },
  { 6, "{1}-{0}" },
  { 7, "{1}{0}-" },
  { 8, "-{1} {0}" },
  { 9, "-{0} {1}" },
  { 10, "{1} {0}-)" },
  { 11, "{0} {1}-" },
  { 12, "{0} -{1}" },
  { 13, "{1}- {0}" },
  { 14, "({0} {1})" },
  { 15, "({1} {0})" }
};
var currencyPattern = value >= Decimal.Zero
  ? currencyPositivePatterns[numberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern]
  : currencyNegativePatterns[numberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern];
var formattedValue = String.Format(
  currencyPattern,
  numberFormat.CurrencySymbol,
  formattedNumber
);
```

The value of `formattedValue` is `₹ -1,23,456.79` which is the same as you get when evaluating `value.ToString("C", cultureInfo)`. Obviously, the later is much simpler.

Note that some currency symbols can contain `.` or `'` which have special meaning in a custom numeric format. As a result of this you cannot always create a custom format string to replace `C`. E.g. for the `da-DK` culture the `C` format for a positive number is equivalent to `kr. #,##0.00` except the dot after `kr` will make it impossible to use that format. Instead you have to use an approach where the currency symbol is added after the number has been formatted, or alternatively you can escape the problematic character.

Comment: By reading your answer, I guess there is no easy way to get the custom pattern for a given standard pattern with C#. Thank you for your answer, it will help me build a script that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik unlike decimal separator or thousands separator, there is no format string for the cultures currency. Maybe this is due to the fact that a number is always the same in every culture, but an amount of money is different according to the currency. Thus, you would have to know the currency in advance.

However, if you do know the currency in advance, you can just use the currency symbol as a normal literal character.

Thus, you could use "0.000 €" (don't French people use the , as their decimal separator?).

Comment: Sorry, may be my question wasn't clear enougth, but it is not about only the currency format, but converting all the different standard format to the custom equivalent. I added examples to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the culture in advance, you can get the format string that's used for currency and use it yourself.

In your example, you would retrieve the `CultureInfo` object for the fr-FR culture using this:

```
CultureInfo French = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

You could just pass this `CultureInfo` object to the `ToString()` method, or you could get the `NumberFormatInfo` object from the `CultureInfo`:

```
NumberFormatInfo numberFormat = French.NumberFormat;
```

The `NumberFormatInfo` object has the following properties: `CurrencySymbol`, `CurrencyDecimalDigits`, `CurrencyDecimalSeparator`, 'CurrencyGroupSeparator`,`CurrencyGroupSizes`.  Using them, you can construct your own format string:

```
string fmt = numberFormat.CurrencySymbol + "#" + numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator;

for ( int i = 0; i < numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSizes - 1; i++ ) 
    fmt += "#";

fmt += "0" + numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;

for ( int d = 0; i < numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits; i++ )
    fmt += "0";
```

There are two other properties of the NumberFormatInfo class called `CurrencyNegativePattern` and `CurrencyPositivePattern`, which tell you where the decimal symbol & sign go, or whether to put negative values in parentheses.  I'll leave it to you to decide if you need these & write the code necessary to build the format string.